# How To use CASE statement in GROUP BY clause in doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Hi am working on a project where i want to group the data i.e. group the record with id is present and if id is null then don't apply group by
e.g. i have 1,2,3,NULL,NULL,1 it should give output 1,2,3,NULL,NULL.My query gives proper output in database but gives error when i am working with that query in doctrine.Thanks in advance

```
            $em = $this->getEntityManager(); 
            $queryBuilder123 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $queryBuilder123->select("obj.batchFormationId as batchId")
                    ->add('from', 'Owner\Entity\Batchformation obj')
                    ->leftjoin('\Owner\Entity\Batchtrainer', 'br', Join::WITH, 'br.batchFormationId=obj.batchFormationId')
                    ->groupBy("br.batchFormationId, CASE WHEN br.batchFormationId IS NULL THEN obj.batchFormationId ELSE 0 END");
            $result123 = $queryBuilder123->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: What error is given?

Comment: Cannot apply group by to unidentified variable or result variable